# How to use Map Network Drive to store files on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: file-sharing

I use Windows Server 2008 R2.

The server is on a virtual machine.

How can I share a folder on the server, and map a drive to it?

Comment: I think you have the version wrong; did you mean Server 2008 R2?

Comment: @axus It's Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter

Answer (score 1):

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770880(v=ws.11).aspx

#### Server Side

Open Computer Management (right-click the Start icon, Computer Management)

In the console tree, click System Tools, click Shared Folders, and then click Shares.

On the Action menu, click New Share.

Follow the steps in the Create a Shared Folder Wizard, and then click Finish.

#### Client Side

Browse to \\servername\

If that doesn't work, you can add read permissions to "Everyone" on the server.

In the Tools menu, you can "Map to Network Drive".